# linear function of a convex set

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose K $\subset \mathbb{R^2}$ is a convex set. If $x\in\partial K$, which means the boundary of K, show there is a linear function $l_x:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $l_x(x)\geq l_x(y)$ for all $y\in K \backslash \{x\}$. Thanks for any hint!

Comment: There is a line that passes through $x$, such that all the points in $K$ lie on one side of (or on) the hyperplane.  This should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result is called the "supporting hyper-plane theorem" and can be derived easily from another theorem, called the "separating hyper-plane theorem". The proof of this is a little lengthy, but can be found in the book of Stephen Boyd on "Convex Optimization" (http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/ ) on pages 46-51. It is nicely explained there, so I figured I point you directly to the source.